# Am I using upstart correctly?

Tags: 12.04, startup, upstart, init.d

I'm trying to write a startup script for my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop that pings my Netgear router every 30 seconds (this is necessary as a nasty workaround for a separate problem I'm having). I read [this tutorial here](http://geeknme.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/getting-started-with-upstart-in-ubuntu/), and it seems that I could accomplish this with a simple `keep-alive.conf` script:

```
script
    ping -i 30 192.168.1.1
end script
```

If that's correct, then I *assume* I just need to save this script to `/etc/init.d/keep-alive.conf`?

I'm also not seeing how I tie the execution of this script to a "startup" event...

Thanks in advance for help on placing the script, and connecting to startup events!

Comment: I think you need to add it to `/etc/init`. Also you probably need some stanza like `start on (started network-manager)` to make it start after network is up.

Answer (score 2):

Salem's comment is correct. Upstart has job configurations at `/etc/init`. `start on started network-manager` is also a reasonable choice.

You might also need to put `respawn` stanza in case ping exits for some reason. Adding `stop on stopping network-manager` might also be reasonable so ping will exit at shutdown.

Complete script might looks like this:

```
start on started network-manager
stop on stopping network-manager
respawn
exec ping -i 30 192.168.1.1
```

and would be placed at `/etc/init/keep-alive.conf`.